# Signals not going forward from initial state in Verilog test bench

Tags: verilog, iverilog, edaplayground

I am working with a system of two d_flipflops (DFFs) connected to each other (with output,q, of first DFF connected to input,d, of second flipflops. I created sub-modules of DFFs and embedded them into a top module. I then created a test bench. However the problem is that the simulation doesn't progress beyond the initial state irrespective of the time-delays I provide. It says simulation is finished at t=0. while there is no error in compilation, I dont understand whats wrong with my code. I also tried providing absolute time values as delays in test bench (e.g #50ns instead of #50) but of no use. I tried simulating this in iverilog and also tried different compilers from EDAplayground. It would be of great help to me if someone could provide insights to my problem. 
Thank you!

```html
module d_ff(d, clk, reset, q, q_not);

input d, clk, reset;

output q, q_not;

reg q, q_not;



always @ (reset or posedge clk)
begin
 if (reset == 0)
 begin
  q<=d;
  
  q_not <= ~d;
 end
 else 
 begin 
  q<=1'b0;
  
  q_not <= 1'b1; 
 end

end


endmodule




module main(d, clk, reset, q2, q2_not, q1_not);

input d, clk, reset;

output q2, q2_not, q1_not;


wire d2;

d_ff dup(.d(d), .clk(clk), .reset(reset), .q(d2), .q_not(q1_not));
d_ff dup2(.d(d2), .clk(clk), .reset(reset), .q(q2), .q_not(q2_not));



initial
begin
$display("end of main module");
$finish;
end

endmodule
```

Here is the testbench:

```html
// Code your testbench here
// or browse Examples
`timescale 1 ns / 100 ps /// 100ps


module main_tb;


reg d, clk, reset;

wire q2, q2_not, q1_not;


main UUT(.d(d), .clk(clk), .reset(reset), .q2(q2), .q2_not(q2_not), .q1_not(q1_not));


initial
begin

clk = 0;
d=1'b0;
reset=1'b1;
#500ns reset=1'b0;

end

always begin
#50ns clk = !clk;

end


initial
begin
  $dumpfile("dump.vcd");
$dumpvars;
end


initial
begin
$monitor("clk = %b, d=%b, reset=%b, q=%b, q_not=%b, d2_not=%b", clk,d,reset, q2,q2_not, q1_not);


#500 reset =1'b1;
#500 d=1'b1;
#500 reset =1'b0;
#500 d=1'b0;
#500 reset = 1'b0;
#500 d=1'b0;
#500 reset = 1'b0;
#500 d=1'b0;
#500 d=1'b1;
#100 reset =1'b1;
#500 d = 1'b1;
 
#50000ns $finish;
end

endmodule
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
initial
begin
   $display("end of main module");
   $finish;
end
```

Is killing your simulation as all initial statements are run in **parallel**. Remove it and put a $finish or $stop at the end of the main initial.
Also better to move all clk assignment into the clk block, the same with reset and b:

```
initial
begin
   clk = 1'b0;
   forever 
      #50ns clk = !clk;
end


initial
begin
   $monitor("clk = %b, d=%b, reset=%b, q=%b, q_not=%b, d2_not=%b", clk,d,reset, q2,q2_not, q1_not);
   d=1'b0;
   reset=1'b1;
   #500ns reset=1'b0;
   #500 reset =1'b1;
   #500 d=1'b1;
   #500 reset =1'b0;
   #500 d=1'b0;
   ...
   $finish; // $stop;
end
```